# Combinations' Problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A person has six friends and during a certain vacation, he met them during several dinners. He found that he dined:-

with all the six exactly on one day,

with every five of them on $2$ days,

with every four of them on $3$ days,

with every three of them on $4$ days, and,

with every two of them on $5$ days.

Further every friend was present at $7$ dinners and every friend was absent at seven dinners.
How many dinners did he have alone?

I got puzzled with so much of information and couldn't get the answer. Please help.

Comment: I'd start with the bit of information that "every friend was present at 7 dinners and ... absent" at 7 dinners.  So to begin, there must have been 14 dinners in all to account for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He had one mean alone and one meal with each friend alone.  One meal had all 6 friends present. All other meals involved 5 attendees and one absent friend.  The easiest way to solve this is to make a table for all 14 dinners and all 6 friends.

Below is a solution where 1 means present (though it would be identical practically if 0 ment present).

[ \begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{Friend} & Adam & Bob&Charlie&Dave&Evgeni&Fred \\
\mbox{Dinner 1} & 1 & 1&1&1&1&1 \\
\mbox{Dinner 2} & 0 & 1&1&1&1&1 \\
\mbox{Dinner 3} & 1 & 0&1&1&1&1 \\
\mbox{Dinner 4} & 1 & 1&0&1&1&1 \\
\mbox{Dinner 5} & 1 & 1&1&0&1&1 \\
\mbox{Dinner 6} & 1 & 1&1&1&0&1 \\
\mbox{Dinner 7} & 1 & 1&1&1&1&0 \\
\mbox{Dinner 8} & 0 & 0&0&0&0&0 \\
\mbox{Dinner 9} & 1 & 0&0&0&0&0 \\
\mbox{Dinner 10} & 0 & 1&0&0&0&0 \\
\mbox{Dinner 11} & 0 & 0&1&0&0&0 \\
\mbox{Dinner 12} & 0 & 0&0&1&0&0 \\
\mbox{Dinner 13} & 0 & 0&0&0&1&0 \\
\mbox{Dinner 14} & 0 & 0&0&0&0&1 \end{array}]

Answer (score 1):

If he ate with $\ell\ge k$ friends, that counts as eating with $k$ friends in $\binom{\ell}{k}$ different ways. You can then use the principle of inclusion-exclusion to determine the number of days he ate with exactly $k$ friends. The expression that results is
$$
\sum_{\ell=k}^6 (-1)^{\ell-k}d_\ell\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{6}{\ell},
$$
where $d_\ell$ is the number of days on which he ate with each group of $\ell$ friends, that is, $d_6=1$, $d_5=2$, $d_4=3$, $d_3=4$, $d_2=5$, and $d_1=7$.

More formally, let $S$ be a subset of the friends and let $S'$ be the complementary subset. Let $E_S$ be the set of days on which only the members of $S$ were present for dinner. For $F\subseteq S'$, let $D_{S,F}$ be the set of days on which the members of $S$, the members of $F$, and possibly other friends were present for dinner. Then
$$
\lvert E_S\rvert=\lvert D_{S,\emptyset}\rvert-\sum_{\lvert F\rvert=1}\lvert D_{S,F}\rvert+\sum_{\lvert F\rvert=2}\lvert D_{S,F}\rvert-\ldots+(-1)^{\lvert S'\rvert}D_{S,S'}.
$$
Summing over all $S$ of cardinality $k$ gives the expression of the previous paragraph since there are $\binom{6}{\lvert S\rvert+\lvert F\rvert}$ ways to choose the set $S\cup F$, $d_{\lvert S\rvert+\lvert F\rvert}$ days on which that set of friends was present for dinner, and $\binom{\lvert S\rvert+\lvert F\rvert}{\lvert S\rvert}$ ways to decompose that set as a set $S$ and a set $F$.

Evaluating the sum explicitly gives

# days with exactly $6$ friends:
$$
1\cdot1\cdot1 = 1,
$$

# days with exactly $5$ friends:
$$
2\cdot1\cdot6-1\cdot6\cdot1 = 6,
$$

# days with exactly $4$ friends:
$$
3\cdot1\cdot15-2\cdot5\cdot6+1\cdot15\cdot1 = 0,
$$

# days with exactly $3$ friends:
$$
4\cdot1\cdot20-3\cdot4\cdot15+2\cdot10\cdot6-1\cdot20\cdot1 = 0,
$$

# days with exactly $2$ friends:
$$
5\cdot1\cdot15-4\cdot3\cdot20+3\cdot6\cdot15-2\cdot10\cdot6+1\cdot15\cdot1 = 0,
$$

# days with exactly $1$ friend:
\begin{align}
&7\cdot1\cdot6-5\cdot2\cdot15+4\cdot3\cdot20-3\cdot4\cdot15+2\cdot5\cdot6\\
&\quad-1\cdot6\cdot1 = 6.
\end{align}

This accounts for $13$ of the $14$ days, so he ate alone on one day.

Note that there is a more compact expression for the sum of these expressions over all values of $k$ (from $1$ to $6$):
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^6\sum_{\ell=k}^6(-1)^{\ell-k}d_\ell\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{6}{\ell}&=\sum_{\ell=1}^6 (-1)^\ell d_\ell\binom{6}{\ell}\sum_{k=1}^\ell(-1)^k\binom{\ell}{k}\\
&=-\sum_{\ell=1}^6 (-1)^\ell d_\ell\binom{6}{\ell}\\
&=-(-7\cdot6+5\cdot15-4\cdot20+3\cdot15-2\cdot6+1\cdot1)\\
&=13.
\end{align}

The lengthier calculation, however, has the advantage that it shows that all the  numbers fall between $0$ and $14$, which is necessary for the problem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $F=\{0,\dots,5\}$ be the set of friends. For each subset $S \subseteq F$, let nonnegative integer decision variable $x_S$ indicate the number of times that subset is the guest list for a dinner.  The constraints are:
\begin{align}
\sum_{S \subseteq F:\ T \subseteq S} x_S &= 7-k &&\text{for $k \in \{2,\dots,6\}$ and $T \subseteq F$ such that $|T|=k$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{S \subseteq F:\ i \in S} x_S &= 7 &&\text{for $i\in F$} \tag2 \\
\sum_{S \subseteq F:\ i \notin S} x_S &= 7 &&\text{for $i\in F$} \tag3
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ forces each $k$-subset to appear the correct number of times.
Constraint $(2)$ forces each friend to be present for $7$ dinners.
Constraint $(3)$ forces each friend to be absent for $7$ dinners.

There are $2^6=64$ variables and $\sum_{k=2}^6\binom{6}{k}+6+6=69$ constraints, and the solution turns out to be unique, even if you do not force $x_S$ to be a nonnegative integer.  Explicitly, here are the constraints, where each $S$ is expressed in binary notation (for example, $x_3 = x_{\{0,1\}}$):
$$
x_{3} + x_{7} + x_{11} + x_{15} + x_{19} + x_{23} + x_{27} + x_{31} + x_{35} + 
x_{39} + x_{43} + x_{47} + x_{51} + x_{55} + x_{59} + x_{63} = 5 \\ 
x_{5} + x_{7} + x_{13} + x_{15} + x_{21} + x_{23} + x_{29} + x_{31} + x_{37} + 
x_{39} + x_{45} + x_{47} + x_{53} + x_{55} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 5 \\ 
x_{6} + x_{7} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{38} + 
x_{39} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 5 \\ 
x_{9} + x_{11} + x_{13} + x_{15} + x_{25} + x_{27} + x_{29} + x_{31} + x_{41} + 
x_{43} + x_{45} + x_{47} + x_{57} + x_{59} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{10} + x_{11} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{42} +
x_{43} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{44} +
x_{45} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{17} + x_{19} + x_{21} + x_{23} + x_{25} + x_{27} + x_{29} + x_{31} + x_{49} +
x_{51} + x_{53} + x_{55} + x_{57} + x_{59} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{18} + x_{19} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{50} +
x_{51} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{20} + x_{21} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{52} +
x_{53} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{24} + x_{25} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{56} +
x_{57} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{33} + x_{35} + x_{37} + x_{39} + x_{41} + x_{43} + x_{45} + x_{47} + x_{49} +
x_{51} + x_{53} + x_{55} + x_{57} + x_{59} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{34} + x_{35} + x_{38} + x_{39} + x_{42} + x_{43} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{50} +
x_{51} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{36} + x_{37} + x_{38} + x_{39} + x_{44} + x_{45} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{52} +
x_{53} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{40} + x_{41} + x_{42} + x_{43} + x_{44} + x_{45} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{56} +
x_{57} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{48} + x_{49} + x_{50} + x_{51} + x_{52} + x_{53} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{56} +
x_{57} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 5 \\
x_{7} + x_{15} + x_{23} + x_{31} + x_{39} + x_{47} + x_{55} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{11} + x_{15} + x_{27} + x_{31} + x_{43} + x_{47} + x_{59} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{13} + x_{15} + x_{29} + x_{31} + x_{45} + x_{47} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{19} + x_{23} + x_{27} + x_{31} + x_{51} + x_{55} + x_{59} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{21} + x_{23} + x_{29} + x_{31} + x_{53} + x_{55} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{25} + x_{27} + x_{29} + x_{31} + x_{57} + x_{59} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{35} + x_{39} + x_{43} + x_{47} + x_{51} + x_{55} + x_{59} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{37} + x_{39} + x_{45} + x_{47} + x_{53} + x_{55} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{38} + x_{39} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{41} + x_{43} + x_{45} + x_{47} + x_{57} + x_{59} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{42} + x_{43} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{44} + x_{45} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{49} + x_{51} + x_{53} + x_{55} + x_{57} + x_{59} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{50} + x_{51} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{52} + x_{53} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{56} + x_{57} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 4 \\
x_{15} + x_{31} + x_{47} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{23} + x_{31} + x_{55} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{27} + x_{31} + x_{59} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{29} + x_{31} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{39} + x_{47} + x_{55} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{43} + x_{47} + x_{59} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{45} + x_{47} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{51} + x_{55} + x_{59} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{53} + x_{55} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{57} + x_{59} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 3 \\
x_{31} + x_{63} = 2 \\
x_{47} + x_{63} = 2 \\
x_{55} + x_{63} = 2 \\
x_{59} + x_{63} = 2 \\
x_{61} + x_{63} = 2 \\
x_{62} + x_{63} = 2 \\
x_{63} = 1 \\
x_{1} + x_{3} + x_{5} + x_{7} + x_{9} + x_{11} + x_{13} + x_{15} + x_{17} + x_{19}
+ x_{21} + x_{23} + x_{25} + x_{27} + x_{29} + x_{31} + x_{33} + x_{35} + x_{37} + x_{39} + x_{41} + x_{43}
+ x_{45} + x_{47} + x_{49} + x_{51} + x_{53} + x_{55} + x_{57} + x_{59} + x_{61} + x_{63} = 7 \\
x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{6} + x_{7} + x_{10} + x_{11} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{18} + 
x_{19} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{34} + x_{35} + x_{38} + x_{39} + x_{42} +
x_{43} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{50} + x_{51} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 7 \\
x_{4} + x_{5} + x_{6} + x_{7} + x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{20} + 
x_{21} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{36} + x_{37} + x_{38} + x_{39} + x_{44} +
x_{45} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{52} + x_{53} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 7 \\
x_{8} + x_{9} + x_{10} + x_{11} + x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{24} + 
x_{25} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{40} + x_{41} + x_{42} + x_{43} + x_{44} +
x_{45} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{56} + x_{57} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 7 \\
x_{16} + x_{17} + x_{18} + x_{19} + x_{20} + x_{21} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{24} + 
x_{25} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} + x_{48} + x_{49} + x_{50} + x_{51} + x_{52} +
x_{53} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{56} + x_{57} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 7 \\
x_{32} + x_{33} + x_{34} + x_{35} + x_{36} + x_{37} + x_{38} + x_{39} + x_{40} + 
x_{41} + x_{42} + x_{43} + x_{44} + x_{45} + x_{46} + x_{47} + x_{48} + x_{49} + x_{50} + x_{51} + x_{52} +
x_{53} + x_{54} + x_{55} + x_{56} + x_{57} + x_{58} + x_{59} + x_{60} + x_{61} + x_{62} + x_{63} = 7 \\
x_{0} + x_{2} + x_{4} + x_{6} + x_{8} + x_{10} + x_{12} + x_{14} + x_{16} + x_{18} 
+ x_{20} + x_{22} + x_{24} + x_{26} + x_{28} + x_{30} + x_{32} + x_{34} + x_{36} + x_{38} + x_{40} + x_{42}
+ x_{44} + x_{46} + x_{48} + x_{50} + x_{52} + x_{54} + x_{56} + x_{58} + x_{60} + x_{62} = 7 \\
x_{0} + x_{1} + x_{4} + x_{5} + x_{8} + x_{9} + x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{16} + x_{17} +
x_{20} + x_{21} + x_{24} + x_{25} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{32} + x_{33} + x_{36} + x_{37} + x_{40} + x_{41} +
x_{44} + x_{45} + x_{48} + x_{49} + x_{52} + x_{53} + x_{56} + x_{57} + x_{60} + x_{61} = 7 \\
x_{0} + x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{8} + x_{9} + x_{10} + x_{11} + x_{16} + x_{17} +
x_{18} + x_{19} + x_{24} + x_{25} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{32} + x_{33} + x_{34} + x_{35} + x_{40} + x_{41} +
x_{42} + x_{43} + x_{48} + x_{49} + x_{50} + x_{51} + x_{56} + x_{57} + x_{58} + x_{59} = 7 \\
x_{0} + x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5} + x_{6} + x_{7} + x_{16} + x_{17} + 
x_{18} + x_{19} + x_{20} + x_{21} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{32} + x_{33} + x_{34} + x_{35} + x_{36} + x_{37} +
x_{38} + x_{39} + x_{48} + x_{49} + x_{50} + x_{51} + x_{52} + x_{53} + x_{54} + x_{55} = 7 \\
x_{0} + x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5} + x_{6} + x_{7} + x_{8} + x_{9} + 
x_{10} + x_{11} + x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{32} + x_{33} + x_{34} + x_{35} + x_{36} + x_{37} +
x_{38} + x_{39} + x_{40} + x_{41} + x_{42} + x_{43} + x_{44} + x_{45} + x_{46} + x_{47} = 7 \\
x_{0} + x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5} + x_{6} + x_{7} + x_{8} + x_{9} + 
x_{10} + x_{11} + x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{16} + x_{17} + x_{18} + x_{19} + x_{20} + x_{21} +
x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{24} + x_{25} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} = 7
$$
You can easily solve this linear system of equations by hand by starting from the trivial constraint $x_{63}=1$ and substituting this value in the other constraints, some of which then become trivial.  Repeat until all variables are determined, or just solve for $x_0$.  The unique solution is
$$x_{0}=x_{1}=x_{2}=x_{4}=x_{8}=x_{16}=x_{31}=x_{32}=x_{47}=x_{55}=x_{59}=x_{61}=x_{62}=x_{63} = 1$$ with all other $x_S=0$.  In particular, $x_0=1$, so only one dinner is eaten with no friends.